# Python 3.4 TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Tags: python

Just to say I know this question has been answered before, but I'm finding it hard to apply it to my situation.

```
cake = ('Chocolate Cakes')

cake_amnt = int(input('How many',cake,'would you like to make?'))
```

When I run the code above I get this error:

```
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

My questions are: What does this error mean? How do I fix my code so that I don't get the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` takes only a single string, so to concatenate instead of

```
cake_amnt = int(input('How many',cake,'would you like to make?'))
```

You should use `format` to build the string

```
cake_amnt = int(input('How many {} would you like to make?'.format(cake)))
```

Or use the `+` operator to perform concatenation

```
cake_amnt = int(input('How many ' + cake + ' would you like to make?'))
```